# SQL Server user lost access to view

Tags: sql-server

I've experienced that a user lost the his access to a specific view unexpectedly.
I had dropped and afterwards re-created the view yesterday so can this be the reason ?

Comment: If you dropped the view, all permissions that had been granted to read from this view are gone. After recreating, you'll need to grant those permissions again, to the appropriate users / groups

Comment: *"I had dropped and afterwards re-created the view yesterday so can this be the reason ?"* Yes. If the `USER` had explicit access to the `VIEW` before and you `DROP`ped it, you removed that explicit access with it. If you didn't add it back, they won't have explicit access unless you `GRANT` it again.

Comment: From the [DROP VIEW (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/drop-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) documentation: "When you drop a view, the definition of the view and other information about the view is deleted from the system catalog. All permissions for the view are also deleted."

Comment: Thank you. Is there a possibility this behaviour to be changed?

Comment: *"Is there a possibility this behaviour to be changed?"* No, because it's by design. Plus, it doesn't make any sense for permissions for an object that **doesn't exist** to be retained.

Comment: Instead of dropping and creating the view, use `ALTER VIEW` instead. That will retain permissions.

Comment: Thank you All.
@Dan Guzan , that's  the most appropriate solution, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, object permissions are also removed when a database object is dropped. It is necessary to re-grant permissions after the object is recreated.

Consider using ALTER VIEW instead of DROP/CREATE. ALTER will retain existing view permissions.